# Major causes of mysql/Innodb crash and restart

Tags: mysql, database, crash, innodb

After a recent DB crash with no RCA from our vendor. I'm left want to expand my knowledge on what sort of things can cause a database to crash.

In our specific case the logs show record index mis-matches just before the crash. We believe this was due to copying .frm and .idb files to another db rather than using mysqldump. There are logged warnings about that for about a week prior to the crash, starting when they were copied. But would it really take so long for the DB to crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, most crashes are due to hardware errors, i.e. your disk is failing. Second most common is user error, like moving InnoDB tablespaces around like they're normal files (you already know, don't do that). Third is bugs in MySQL, because all software has bugs.

It's certainly possible to take an indefinite amount of time before user activity accesses the code path that causes a crash. Can't make any conclusion from that.

Ultimately, you have to create redundancy to protect against crashes. This is especially important for databases. Examples of redundancy:

- Use RAID 1 or RAID 10 to do disk mirroring
- Use replication to copy data another MySQL instance continuously
- Host the other MySQL instance on another physical computer, best if it's on a separate rack in your data center
- You might even have another replica in another region of the country

Comment: Or RAID-5 (to be a bit cheaper, but still get redundancy)

Comment: Yep, RAID-5 is fine for HA, but not as good for performance because of write amplification when you write small changes.

Comment: My experience says otherwise.  Only 2 drives need to be touched, not the full parity set.  Furthermore, the block(s) that need updating are probably cached.  (Granted, my experience is with a hardware controller that had BBWC.)  I used the SlowLog to measure changes pre-/post-switching from -5 to -10.  Only one or two cases (out of hundreds) showed a speedup.

Comment: I guess the BBWC helped with that. It could also be that the writes were aligned with RAID stripes, so it would calculate parity from the write payload instead of needing to read other drives to calculate the parity. Good to know!